# Programatically cloning elements in Sparx EA

Tags: javascript, scripting, enterprise-architect

I have a package structured somewhat like this:

```
Package A
    Element "A"
    Element "B"
    Element "A"
Package B
```

I want to copy a subset of the elements in package A to package B using JavaScript.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no build-in method to clone an `EA.Element`, but there is one to clone an `EA.Package`: `EA.Package.Clone()`

So the easiest way would be:

- Create a temporary `EA.Package`
- Move the elements you want to clone into the temp package
- Clone the temp package
- Move the elements back to their original location
- Move the cloned elements in the cloned package to their destination
- Delete the temp and cloned temp package

Comment: While this is a perfectly functional workaround, it sounds like an enhancement request for a EA.Element.Clone() method would be sensible, since should any of the above steps could fail or have issues, it would leave your original model "damaged".

Comment: I agree. Don't hesitate to send one in: http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/feature_request.html

Comment: I've gone ahead and done so. We'll see if anything happens.

Answer (score 0):

`EA.Element.Clone()` was added for EA 13. (Well done John for the feature request. Well done Sparx for listening)